# is there a way to captilize first word of textformfield automatically and also be able to use capital or small letter after wards

Tags: flutter, dart

Is there a way to automatically make the first word of text form field capital and after wards we can freely make the second word capital or small of our choice for Ex:- Steven Jhons

```
class UpperCaseTextFormatter extends TextInputFormatter {
  @override
  TextEditingValue formatEditUpdate(
      TextEditingValue oldValue, TextEditingValue newValue) {
    return TextEditingValue(
      text: capitalize(newValue.text),
      selection: newValue.selection,
    );
  }
}

String capitalize(String value) {
  if (value.trim().isEmpty) {
    return "";
  } else if (value.isNotEmpty) {
    return "${value[0].toUpperCase()}${value.substring(1).toLowerCase()}";
  } else {
    return "";
  }
}
```

called it inside textformfield like this

```
TextFormField(
                                decoration:
                                    const InputDecoration(hintText: "Name"),
                                controller: nameController,
                                validator: (value) {
                                  if (value == null || value.isEmpty) {
                                    return "Please enter your name";
                                  } else {
                                    return null;
                                  }
                                },
                                textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.words,
                                inputFormatters: <TextInputFormatter>[
                                  UpperCaseTextFormatter()
                                ],
                              ),
```

this is the code i have been using it makes the first word capital but we are not able to make the second or any word capital after ward need some help here thanks.

Answer (score 1):

To capitalize every word, you can use the help of the [`substring`](https://api.dart.dev/stable/2.17.0/dart-core/String/substring.html) method:

```
String capitalize(String str) {
  return str
      .split(' ')
      .map((word) => word.substring(0, 1).toUpperCase() + word.substring(1))
      .join(' ');
}
```

---

```
print(capitalize('john doe')); // John Doe
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try this to make the first letter to uppercase

```dart
TextFormField(
 controller: _textEditingController,
 onChange: (val){
  if(_textEditingController.length > 0)
  {
    _textEditingController.text =  "${_textEditingController[0].toUpperCase()}${ 
    _textEditingController.substring(1)}";
    _textController.selection = TextSelection.fromPosition(TextPosition(offset: _textController.text.length));
   }
 }
)
```

Answer (score 0):

Reading the title of this question makes me think that you only want to capitalize the first word in a TextFormField, not every word? If that is so, why not just use:

```
textCapitalization: TextCapitalization.sentences
```

You will still have freedom afterwards to capitalize subsequent words or not. With the caveat that after a period (`.`) you will get a capitalize word by default, but able to change it obviously.